# A Trivial Pursuit #02 (Entertainment 1/4): Wrong Superhero

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay, movies, literature

<sub>This is part 2 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

- Minecraft character who receives enhanced abilities after taking the Heart-Shaped Herb (5,7)
- Vigilante who patrols the city streets at night wearing one of his many noteworthy items of headgear (6)
- ‘Hero for hire’ with huge uncontrollable anger issues (4,4)
- Accomplished pilot with superhuman strength and a penchant for skimpy underwear and flip-flops (3,5)
- Cybernetic weapons expert usually seen wearing a type of surplice (6,7)
- Desperately impoverished and unpredictable mercenary with regenerative healing powers (8)
- Reformed ex-con who can change size and paint portraits (3-3)
- Interplanetary policeman who loves to glide high in the air, seemingly effortlessly (4-4)
- US Air Force officer with a wide range of abilities and a Booker Prize-winning novel set in a lifeboat (7,6)
- Italian forcefield-generating founding member of the Fantastic IV (9,5)

**If these superheroes are all wrong, then which other superhero will help you put things right?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each answer is made by

> taking the name of an existing superhero (hinted at by a part of each clue) and changing one letter to match the rest of the clue.

1. Minecraft character who receives enhanced abilities after taking the Heart-Shaped Herb (5,7)

> Black Panther -> Block Panther

2. Vigilante who patrols the city streets at night wearing one of his many noteworthy items of headgear (6)

> Batman -> Hatman

3. ‘Hero for hire’ with huge uncontrollable anger issues (4,4)

> Luke Cage -> Luke Rage

4. Accomplished pilot with superhuman strength and a penchant for skimpy underwear and flip-flops (3,5)

> The Thing -> The Thong

5. Cybernetic weapons expert usually seen wearing a type of surplice (6,7)

> Rocket Raccoon -> Rochet Raccoon

6. Desperately impoverished and unpredictable mercenary with regenerative healing powers (8)

> Deadpool -> Deadpoor

7. Reformed ex-con who can change size and paint portraits (3-3)

> Ant-Man -> Art-Man

8. Interplanetary policeman who loves to glide high in the air, seemingly effortlessly (4-4)

> Star-Lord -> Soar-Lord

9. US Air Force officer with a wide range of abilities and a Booker Prize-winning novel set in a lifeboat (7,6)

> Captain Marvel -> Captain [Martel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi)

10. Italian forcefield-generating founding member of the Fantastic IV (9,5)

> Invisible Woman -> Invisible Roman

The clues are ordered

> alphabetically by the replaced letter (A in #1, B in #2 etc).

The hero we need to put things right

> is spelt by the letters we've used to replace the correct one in each clue. These are OHROHRROTR. Justhalf in comments figured out this has one T, two Hs, three Os and four Rs, spelling out **THOR**.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although this puzzle was designed to require 10 'wrong superheroes' rather than just 4... Do you see why?

Comment: one T, two H, three O, four R

Comment: Ahh, that's clever!